# Search links within a web page

Tags: search, browser-addons, web

I have a page that links multiple documents. I'd like to perform a recursive search (starting at that page and then recursing through links) for a given text phrase.

I'm wondering if there is a browser plugin to do something like this. Any ideas?

I've seen some more manual solutions like: [Search for text in web pages given a list of URLs](https://superuser.com/questions/309699/search-for-text-in-web-pages-given-a-list-of-urls)

Comment: Is this being done on the server or on your local PC requesting items page by page?

Comment: On my local PC. Right now I have to open each page manually and look for a text string. I know there a search engine bots that do something similar, so I was hoping for something an end-user could use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps download the website, then on your computer do a search for the phrase. It should look through each of the files depending on your OS.